# Remove/move a item from a list to another list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a list were new calls are being captured and the list is called "New Orders/Not yet Allocated orders", in that list those others are not yet "In Progress",so what I want when a certain column change,or when a certain column in not null and the status is equals to "New" I want that item to move to another list called "current allocated orders"

Will appreciate your help!

Comment: Have a look at Workflows. Should help.

Comment: Workflow or Event Receiver both can help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your volume of orders if high (going to hit the standard 5000 item threshold quickly) why not just use a single list with multiple views? You could have views based on status (either filtered or grouped) that would allow you to keep the data in once place nicely and avoid complication such as a workflow.